# What do people in Human Resources / Hiring think about resumes with skill bars?

Tags: resume, hiring-process

This question was [asked on graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15488/is-having-a-skills-bar-chart-on-a-resume-a-good-idea), but I wanted an HR perspective. See the bottom-right of the resume below.

[image: example]

Comment: Are you asking specifically about resumes for graphic designers? Resumes for graphic designers are a whole different ballgame from other resumes.

Comment: Do you feel some HR people may not recognize the significance of the font size for the skills on the left, so they need the graph?

Answer (score 10):

I'm not HR but I am involved in selecting candidates based on resumes.

I appreciate that the whole vehicle for a graphic design resume is different from that in my field and I need to make allowances for that while looking at the sample here. I'm going to proceed by assuming you're asking about this idea as a general thing, as I suspect that this kind of design for a graphic designer is part of their portfolio of work in a minor way more than it is a traditional resume.

I find the idea of "skill bars" presumptuous and rather useless. How can I possibly compare those "grades" to the skills of someone else? What if they have the same idea and give themselves 27 out of 30 for the same skills?

How can I tell whether or not hiring that person will solve the problem I'm trying to solve by hiring someone?

Don't *tell* a hiring manager how good you think you are, that's for them to decide. *Show* them how good you actually are. That is, of course, precisely what's happening in that sample, but not because of the number of dots in the skill bars.

Comment: +1. And, as @DJClayworth pointed out, this sheet is intended specifically to push the individual as a graphic designer and the skill bars are more a sample of their work than anything inherently meaningful. (Though if this is intended to be an example of the designer's best work, I really can't say I'm all that favorably impressed.)

Comment: Is it more useless than a text skill assessment though, like "familiar with" or "experienced with"? I agree that something like "Used X for a project that Y" is a more substantial statement.

Comment: @user3038802 exactly - "expert in *$blah*" is 'telling me'. "Managed the delivery of *$foo* project using *$blah* project manglement methodology, 20% under budget and on time" is 'showing me'.

Comment: Ever been asked "On a scale from 1 - 10 ..."?

Comment: @JeffO not asked to fill that in on a resume or cover letter, no. Being asked to do so in person can be a conversational gambit to open a discussion on that skill, or to see how a candidate talks about their strengths and weaknesses, and is therefore entirely different from just putting it on your own resume yourself in my opinion.

Comment: I have to say I find the scale useful regardless of its unknown lower/upper-bound. It reads to me how confident the person is in that area. In this case, there is very little that cannot be done in Photoshop, but making outstanding photography is slightly below par. I do understand the other points of view though, but I agree with @user3038802 that 'Adept, proficient, knowledgeable, etc.' is just as vague.

Comment: @Xrylite "adept", etc. are just as vague... *absolutely*, there's no argument there. Again *show*, don't just *tell*. Outside of the context of a graphical design resume that's also working as a portfolio piece, drawing a series of 16 dots and colouring 14 of them in for Unix, say, tells me that you know how to make dots and you're confident in your own abilities. It doesn't actually show me your skills. That's if I even *see* the resume as a hiring manager; HR might well bin the resume as "doesn't meet criteria" (lets put the debate about the rights and wrongs of that aside for now)

Comment: @RobM, +1 for "project manglement methodology" :-D

Comment: I think if it's fair for recruiters to ask you to self-rate, it's fair to do it on a resume. Honestly, who has room for did foo on project bar using technology baz on their resume unless they're fresh out of school. Listing every detail like that may help with automated systems, but will make a real person's eyes bleed.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you put things on a resume that have some sort of measurement or you just state something mater-of-fact:  Sold "X" amount of widgets in first quarter. Managed project on time & budget 75% of the time. Built commercial website using technology XYZ.

I don't see how a bar graph helps an HR person in this case. They should be very familiar with the skills listed and if you indicate you're an 8 on photoshop and 3 on photography, they should get the idea and don't need a bar graph to display the differences in a graphical nature to focus on the point.

Bar graphs also help to show trends in some situations. Maybe if you were to put previous salaries, you could demonstrate how you've been able to get jobs with increasing responsibility and higher performance evaluations. I don't suggest that, but can't find much of a better use for a bar graph on a resume outside of skill sets.

Usually, these types of things are brought up during an interview, so there's not need to put them on a resume. Why say you're not very good at something if they don't even ask?